# CKEDITOR not showing up

Tags: .net, ckeditor

I am using ck editor in my asp.net page.I have a problem with it the ckeditor doesnt work for me .
I have updatepanel and inside it i have a detailsview. I need to place my ckeditor in insert and edit templates of the detailsview. But when I open the webpage i could see that the ckeditor is not loading.

I have added the ckeditor folder and added the javascript file

Also I have added

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     if (CKEDITOR.instances('TextBoxArticleBody')) {
         CKEDITOR.instances['TextBoxArticleBody'].destroy();
     }
     CKEDITOR.replace('TextBoxArticleBody');
 </script>
```

Can some one guide me please .

Thanks

Comment: Can you verify that the ID of the element rendered on the page matches 'TextBoxArticleBody'? Often ASP.NET naming containers with prepend some extra stuff on the front of your elements, particularly if they are ASP.NET controls.

Comment: yes it matches i donno why i don tget ckeditor

Comment: You should probably add a bit more source so we can see what's happening here.

Comment: Do you get any Console messages? Is this issue still valid? Do you have a solution? If so, please post it.